# A few improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\displaystyle \begin{align*}
  & \int_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\text{d}x}{1+{{x}^{n}}}} \\ 
 & \int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{\frac{{{x}^{2m}}}{1+{{x}^{2n}}}\text{d}x} \\ 
 & \int_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{{{x}^{s-1}}}{1+x}\text{d}x} \\ 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: What about them?  Do you have a question?

Comment: There must be something wrong with MSE at the moment. Your question mark doesn't appear on my screen.

Comment: What class are these questions from? Those are rather non-trivial for introductory Calculus.

Comment: You can use the [following technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254417/how-to-solve-this-question-related-to-definite-integration/254452#254452) to evaluate them

Comment: Do you want to compute them or determine under what conditions they converge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of them can be solved using the beta function technique. See [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255875/improper-integration-involving-complex-analytic-arguments/255923#255923), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254417/how-to-solve-this-question-related-to-definite-integration/254452#254452), [(III)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575361/applications-of-the-residue-theorem-to-the-evaluation-of-integrals-and-sums). Notice that, the second integral can be written as,

$$ \int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{\frac{{{x}^{2m}}}{1+{{x}^{2n}}}\text{d}x}=2\int_{0 }^{+\infty }{\frac{{{x}^{2m}}}{1+{{x}^{2n}}}\text{d}x}. $$

Comment: I don't feel like that down votes in previous question you've got. Sometimes, some of us forget that we are here just to share our thoughts for solving a problem and help someone to understand a problem but not to war. +1

Comment: @BabakSorouh: As you see, I just suggested an idea for solving the problem, but I do not know why they made all of this argument!! Thanks for comment.

Comment: I made some + for other your answers you made. ;-)

Comment: @BabakSorouh: Thank you. I really appreciate it. This website serves a good purpose for humanity.

Comment: @Babak Did you actually *ma(k)e some + for other (Mhenni's) answers (Mhenni) made* because (you) *don't feel like that down votes in previous question (Mhenni's) got*? Everybody is entitled to one's own opinions about upvotes and downvotes on the site, of course, but if you did vote on some answers **by compensation**, you might wish to reconsider and to stop doing it: this is misleading other users about your opinion of the posts you upvote, and definitely not the way the system is supposed to work.

Comment: I accidentally down voted this because I'm on an iPhone, if you make any edit to the question I will undo it (I was attempting to view up/down casts and accidentally hit down).

Comment: @guy: No problem.