# How to solve the following integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the following integral by parts, but no answers so far.$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{x}{(1+ax)(1+x)}\right]^{K}dx,$$ where $K\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a>0$ is a constant. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Mathematica 9.01 produces $$a^{-K} Gamma[-1 + K] Gamma[1 + K] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[-1 + K,
  K, 2 K, (-1 + a)/a].$$

Comment: The integrand can be rewritten as 
  $$ \left( {\frac {1}{ \left( a-1 \right)  \left( 1+x \right) }}-{\frac {
1}{ \left( a-1 \right)  \left( ax+1 \right) }} \right) ^{K}.
 $$ Then try to apply [the binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula in terms of the [associated Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials)

> $$\frac{ 2\,{4}^{k-1}\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}+k \right)\beta \left( k+1,k-1 \right)}{ {a}^{3/4} \left(   a-1 \right) ^{k-1/2} } 
> P^{\frac{1}{2}}_{\frac{1}{2}-k}\left( {\frac {a+1}{2\sqrt {a}}}\right)\quad \left\{k\geq 2 \cap k\in \mathbb{N}\right\},$$

where $\beta(u,v)$ is the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

**added:** For the case $a=1$, we can find the answer 
$$ {\frac {2\,{4}^{-k}\,\sqrt {\pi }\,\Gamma  \left( k+1 \right) }{ \left( k-
1 \right) \Gamma  \left( k+1/2 \right) }} \quad \left\{k\geq 2 \cap k\in \mathbb{N}\right\},$$

by plugging $a=1$ in the integral using this [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124).

Comment: What's going on when $a=1$?

Comment: @RonGordon: It is clear that it is a special case and it needs to be handled separately by plugging in the integral $a=1$.

Comment: I don't mean to be giving you a hard time, but should the result not be continuous in $a$?  I'm sure that it works out, but I do not see how this is obvious.

Comment: (+1) Just a small comment to make the formula less misterious. Using the change of variables $x=\frac{t}{1-t}$ the integral transforms into $$\int_0^1 \frac{ t^{k} (1-t)^{k-2} }{\left[1-(1-a)t\right]^k} dt.$$
This is clearly a hypergeometric function $_2F_1$ (which can reduce to something else because of special parameter values). The result is continuous in $a$ and it is clear that in the case $a=1$ it can be expressed in terms of gamma functions.

Comment: @O.L.: This was precisely what I was looking for!  You should write this up in a separate post.

Comment: @O.L.: (+1) Nice explanation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to agree with Samrat's answer below for the $ a = 1 $ part. His seems correct though.

Comment: @O.L. Great explanation. Thanks !

Comment: (-1): the procedure does not show the distinguishing features for $K\in\mathbb{N}$ .

Comment: @doraemonpaul: What distinguishing features are you taking about?

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal: As $K$ is a natural number, $\dfrac{x^K}{(1+ax)^K(1+x)^K}$ can do partial fraction.

Comment: @doraemonpaul: You can work it out using the technique you suggested. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=1$ then the integral becomes $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^K}{(1+x)^{2K}}dx$$ Letting $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x}=z$ we get $$I=\int_{0}^{1}z^{K-2}(1-z)^K dz=\beta\left(K-1,K+1\right)$$

I'll write down the results for $a\ne 1$ shortly.