# Evaluate the trigonometric integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{ \sqrt[3]{\tan x} }{ \left( \sin x + \cos x \right)^2 }\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{
\sqrt[3]{\tan x}
}{
\left( \sin x + \cos x \right)^2
}\, dx
$$

This question I use the Kings Property and I equal to cube root of $\tan x$ plus cube root of $\cot x$ divided by $(\sin x+\cos x)^2$ but was stuck after that.

Or if we pull out $\cos x$ from the denominator, then it will be $(\tan x+1)^2$ and then substituting $\tan x$ for $u$. I couldn’t proceed further...

Kindly help
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Hint**: Multiply numerator and denominator of sub-integral function by $\sec^2 x$.

Comment: **Hint**: Let $x=\tan ^{-1}\left(t^3\right)$ and use partial fractions.

Comment: try putting the integral into this form (beta function) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

firstly we have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan^{\frac{1}{3}}x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan^{\frac{1}{3}}x}{(\tan x+1)^2} \sec^2x  dx $$
now put $x\to \tan^{-1} x$ and get
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan^{\frac{1}{3}}x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+1)^2}dx $$
we can use the formula
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{(x+1)^2}dx=\pi n \csc(\pi n) $$
So
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan^{\frac{1}{3}}x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx=\pi \frac{1}{3} \csc \left(\pi \frac{1}{3} \right)=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$
the formula we used can be easily prove by gamma function , but  if you need to solve that integral without gamma function we can find indefinite integral firstly put $x\to \frac{1}{x}$ So
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+1)^2}dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{-1}{3}}}{(x+1)^2}dx $$
So
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+1)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^{\frac{-1}{3}}}{(x+1)^2}dx $$
now put $x \to x^3$ and get
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+1)^2}dx= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{3x^2(x+\frac{1}{x})}{(x^3+1)^2}dx $$
we can use partial fraction but its too long so lets see this trick
$$\frac{3x^2(x+\frac{1}{x})}{(x^3+1)^2}=\frac{3x(x^2+1)}{(x^3+1)^2}-\frac{1+x}{x^3+1}+\frac{1+x}{x^3+1}$$
$$=\frac{-x^4+2x^3+2x-1}{(x^3+1)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}$$
So
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+1)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{-x^4+2x^3+2x-1}{(x^3+1)^2} dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx$$
first integral equals zero (using indefinite integral you can try with) and the second integral can be evaluate using arctan function
$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}} \right)\right)^\infty_0=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$
finally
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan^{\frac{1}{3}}x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} $$

Answer (score 9):

Substitute $t={\tan x}$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{
\sqrt[3]{\tan x}
}{
\left( \sin x + \cos x \right)^2
}\, dx\\
=&\int_0^\infty \frac {t^{1/3}}{(1+t)^2}dt\overset{ibp}
= \int_0^\infty \frac {d(t^{1/3})}{1+t}\overset{t^{1/3}\to t}= \int_0^\infty \frac {dt}{1+t^3}=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Substituting $$\tan x = t^3, \qquad \sec^2 x \,dx = 3 t^2 \,dt,$$ rationalizes the integral, giving
$$3 \int_0^\infty \frac{t^3 \,dt}{(1 + t^3)^2},$$
and integrating by parts with $u = t$, $dv = \frac{t^2 \,dt}{(1 + t^3)^2}$, yields
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{1 + t^3}.$$
To evaluate this latter integral, see [Compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556115/compute-int-0-infty-fracdx1x3?noredirect=1) or, if you're able to use residue calculus, [Integrating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^3}$ using residues.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565388/integrating-int-0-infty-fracdx1x3-using-residues).