# Prove $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}-\log x\right)^3}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2 (\log^2x+\frac{\pi ^2}{4})} dx= \pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

@integralsbot at twitter [posted](https://twitter.com/integralsbot/status/1394226375515525121) interesting integral and complicated integrals that gives $\pi$ as a result. Some of the problems are really difficult to prove, such as

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}-\log x\right)^3}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2 (\log^2x+\frac{\pi ^2}{4})} dx =\pi\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

I've tried to calculate this and it appeared very difficult. The plot of the integrand doesn't look very extraordinary.

[image: orginal_function_plot]

Using partial fraction decomposition, the integral [can be transformed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial%20fraction%20%28%28%5C%5BPi%5D%20x%29%2F2%20-%20Log%5Bx%5D%29%5E3%2F%28%28Log%5Bx%5D%5E2%20%2B%20%5C%5BPi%5D%5E2%2F4%29%20%281%20%2B%20x%5E2%29%5E2%29%20) to the following form:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{3 \pi  x}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2}-\frac{\log (x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{\pi^3 x^3-6 \pi ^2 x^2 \log (x)-3 \pi ^3 x+2 \pi ^2 \log (x)}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2 \left(4\log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)} \right)$$

The first two integrals can be [more](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20from%200%20to%20infinity%20%283%20%CF%80%20x%29%2F%282%20%28x%5E2%20%2B%201%29%5E2%29%20) or [less](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581155/integrate-int-0-infty-frac-logx1x22-dx-without-using-compl) solved
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{3 \pi x}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2} = \frac{3 \pi}{4}, \>\>\>\>\>
\int_{0}^{\infty} -\frac{\log (x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2} = \frac{\pi}{4} $$
to yield:
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{3 \pi  x}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2} - \frac{\log (x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2} \ dx= \pi \tag{2}\label{eq2} $$

This is interesting by itself, since the integrand displays interesting shape with two inflection points of the first derivative. I wouldn't expect it to be equal to $\pi$ (yet the algebra clearly shows that it is).

[image: pi_part_of_integral_plot]

What is even more interesting is

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^3 x^3-6 \pi ^2 x^2 \log (x)-3 \pi ^3 x+2 \pi ^2 \log (x)}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2 \left(4\log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)} = 0 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

which follows from \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2}. This is correct (I've checked numerically with relatively high precision of ~100 decimals). It seems very hard to prove though. The plot of the integrand doesn't appear to suggest any trivial solution:
[image: zero_integral_function_plot]

An  obvious way to transform integral \eqref{eq3} is to expand the numerator:

$$ 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( -\frac{3 \pi ^2 x^2 \log (x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2 \left(4 \log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)}-\frac{3
   \pi ^3 x}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2 \left(4 \log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)}+\frac{\pi ^2 \log
   (x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2 \left(4 \log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)}+\frac{\pi ^3 x^3}{2
   \left(x^2+1\right)^2 \left(4 \log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)} \right), $$

But the resulting integrals are also difficult. (I've tried to solve the second one, since it seems to have the simplest numerator, but didn't managed to get any result). Neither their numerical values (-1.93789..., 3.229820..., -0.322982..., -0.968946...) nor the plots indicate any obvious cancellations. Maybe there is some indirect way to show the integral \eqref{eq3} vanishes without solving it at all.

I don't know where \eqref{eq1} comes from but it seems to be true and interesting. I believe some solution of this integral exists. I post it as an challenge/puzzle. Maybe someone knows it, sees clever substitution, or provides any insight into.

So, the question is: how to prove either \eqref{eq1} or \eqref{eq3}?

Comment: I scrolled down on the twitter profile you linked and it seems like the majority of the integrals are from this site (perhaps with small modifications). Which is not a problem, but (re)posting them might create many duplicates.

Comment: @Zacky I've tried to search following similar topics that where shown when I was asking this question and I checked first few pages of results from approach0 but the thread you linked didn't come up in search. Sorry.

Comment: I also wonder how does this work. If it's truly a bot it is indeed transforming the original questions quite cleverly. I'll look into that, thank you for the observation.

Comment: If it's a fully automated bot, it would have to have a way to check whether the asked question is true, know which equation from question to copy, and transform the original question to similar form (constants elimination in this case?). I suppose that's hardly the case. More likely it's some person that finds the formulas and checks them and bot only posts them on twitter account.

Comment: The question is reopened. It is nice because, between your work and mine, the solution has been obtained in a very simple manner.

Comment: Maybe doable with complex analysis? The poles at $z=\pm i$ are order $2$, and the sum of their residues and hence an integral around an appropriate contour is $0$. First choice of contour would be circle with a keyhole to avoid a branch cut taken along $[0,\infty)$. Above the cut we recover integral (3). But below it, the $\log^2(z)$ in the denominator makes things a bit tricky. I wonder if it's possible to show the latter is purely imaginary so the result you seek would follow...

Answer (score 8):

Let
$$f(x)= \frac{\pi^3 x^3-6 \pi ^2 x^2 \log (x)-3 \pi ^3 x+2 \pi ^2 \log (x)}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2 \left(4\log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)} $$  that is to say
$$f(x)=\frac{\pi ^2 \left(\pi  x \left(x^2-3\right)-2\left(3x^2-1\right) \log
   (x)\right)}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2 \left(4 \log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)}$$
and write
$$I=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx+\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$$ For the second integral, let $x=\frac 1 x$. So, now we have
$$I=\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx-\int_0^1 g(x) \,dx=\int_0^1 [f(x)- g(x)] \,dx$$ with
$$g(x)=\frac{\pi ^2 \left(\pi  \left(3 x^2-1\right)+2 x \left(x^2-3\right) \log
   (x)\right)}{2 x \left(x^2+1\right)^2 \left(4 \log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)}$$
$$f(x)-g(x)=\frac{\pi ^2 \left(\pi  \left(x^4-6 x^2+1\right)-8 x \left(x^2-1\right) \log
   (x)\right)}{2 x \left(x^2+1\right)^2 \left(4 \log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)}$$ and, **numerically**,
$$\int_0^1 [f(x)- g(x)] \,dx=0$$ which still needs to be proved.

In fact, what happens if that
$$\int_0^a [f(x)- g(x)] \,dx=-\int_a^1 [f(x)- g(x)] \,dx$$ where $a$ is the solution of
$$\pi  \left(x^4-6 x^2+1\right)-8 x \left(x^2-1\right) \log (x)=0$$
$$a=0.1928617994587428536765548799193482174970163765555\cdots$$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't manage to clearly see where $I = 0$ comes from yet, but indeed, after splitting $I$ into the two parts at x=1, the two parts cancel each other (I checked that numerically). Why is the x=1 special in that regard? Is it because it's in the $(1+x^2)^2$ in the denominator of $f(x)$? I'm trying to check that with direct computation and analysing the last log integral to be able to do so. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @tpk. It had to be something like that (which is quite common with logarithms). After $x\to \frac 1y$, you have the same expression with a minus sign. If anything is not clear, just tell ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Oh, I've just realised this question is marked as a duplicate. I'll check the linked question, the answer probably lies there.

Comment: Claude, Quite an intriguing integral indeed. I had no problem with the first ibtegrals but failed to show that the third one is nil, even after perfotming the change you ate suggesting. More details on your calculation will be appreciated. fjaclot;

Comment: I second that showing that I = 0 by splitting into the two integrals is not that easy. I checked numerically that it's true and got to the point where I had the same form of the denominator in both integrals ("x" and "y" parts), but was unable to cancel the difference of expressions under the integral sign explicitly.

Comment: This is what I get after substitution and switching integration limits to cancel out the minus sign
$$
I_2 = \int_1^\infty f(x)  =  \left[\begin{aligned}  x &= \frac{1}{y} \\  dx &= -x^2 dy \\ 1 &\rightarrow 1 \\ \infty &\rightarrow 0 \end{aligned}  \right] =
\int_0^1\frac{\frac{\pi ^3}{y^3}-\frac{3 \pi ^3}{y}-\frac{6 \pi ^2 \log \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)}{y^2}+2 \pi ^2 \log \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)}{2 \left(\frac{1}{y^2}+1\right)^2 y^2 \left(4 \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)+\pi ^2\right)}
$$

Comment: then using logarithm properties and the fact, that $y\ge 0$ and canceling $y$'s we get
$$
I_2=\int_0^1 \frac{\pi^3-3 \pi ^3 y^2+6 \pi ^2 y \log (y)-2 \pi ^2 y^3 \log (y)}{2 y \left(1+y^2\right)^2 \left(\pi ^2+4 \log ^2(y)\right)}
$$
to me it still isn't clear why would
$$ 
I = I_1 + I_2 = \int_0^1 f(x) + I_2 = 0 
$$
maybe there's some trick with substitution and/or integration by parts to cleverly shift $y$ from denominator to numerator and then equality/canceling of the integrals would be clear, but I'm unable to see one.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici do you perhaps know where to follow from formula in my previous comment? I still couldn't find a way to show that $I$ = 0.

Comment: @tpk. Back to the problem, I wonder about a possible mistake of mine. As you  did, numerically it is true. Let me work again. I sahll post anything new. Cheers :-)

Comment: @tpk. Now, I am lost ! I found the term but I do not knwo how to prove why it is zero. I continue.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it and try to build on what you came up with.

Comment: @tpk. Why not to post another question asking why $\int_0^1 [f(x)- g(x)] \,dx=0$ ?

Comment: That’s a good idea. I’ll post it later today.

Answer (score 5):

Continue with
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{\pi  x}{2}-\ln x)^3}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2 (\ln^2 x+\frac{\pi ^2}{4})}dx
=\pi+K
\end{align}
where the vanishing integral $K=0$ in (3) is proven below
\begin{align}
K=&\int_{0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\frac{\pi^3}8(x^3-3x) 
+\frac{\pi^2}4 \overset{x\to 1/x}{(1-3x^2)}\ln x }{\left(x^2+1\right)^2 (\ln^2 x+\frac{\pi ^2}{4})}\ dx\\
=& \ \frac{\pi^2}4 \int_0^\infty
 \frac{x^3-3x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\cdot \frac{\frac\pi2-\frac1x\ln x }{\ln^2 x+\frac{\pi ^2}{4}}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac{\pi^2}4 \int_0^\infty
 \frac{x^3-3x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\int_0^1 x^{-t} \sin\frac{\pi t}2dt\  dx\\
 =&\ \frac{\pi^2}4 \int_0^1\sin\frac{\pi t}2\int_0^\infty
 \frac{x^{3-t}-3x^{1-t}}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}dx\  dt\\
=&\ \frac{\pi^3}8 \int_0^1(1-2t)dt=0\\
\end{align}
Note that the following integrals are used above
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 x^{-t} \sin\frac{\pi t}2dt
= \int_0^1 e^{-t\ln x} \sin\frac{\pi t}2dt
=\frac{\frac\pi2-\frac1x \ln x}{\ln^2 x+\frac{\pi^2}4}\\
 &\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1-t}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx =\frac{\pi t}{4\sin\frac{ \pi t}2},\>\>\>
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{3-t}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx =\frac{\pi(2-t)}{4\sin\frac{ \pi t}2}
\end{align}