# Fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}+2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $$f(x)=\large \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}+2}$$ Compute the Fourier transform of $f$.

---

We can factor the denominator to get $$f(x)=\frac1{(\exp(x/2)+\exp(-x/2))^2}=\frac1{(2\cosh(x/2))^2}$$ I'm thinking of using residue from complex analysis. To find the singularity, we have $$\exp(x/2)=-\exp(-x/2)\iff\exp(x)=-1$$ We know $\exp(i\pi)=-1$. So the singularities are $i\pi+2\pi k i $.

Comment: That's good analysis so far.  Do you have a question?

Comment: You meant the singularities are $i\pi + 2k\pi i$, didn't you?

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. My question is: what theorem should I apply next? Does Jordan's lemma apply here? I'm thinking of a semicircular contour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Related techniques: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837556/how-to-compute-this-integral-involving-sech/837763#837763), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926454/calculus-question-improper-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos2x1-sqrt3/926897#926897). First, we recall the Mellin transform of a function $f$

> $$ F(s) =\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}f(x)  dx .$$

Now, making the change of variables $u=e^{x}$ in the original integral gives

> $$I = \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-iwx}}{{\rm e}^{x}}}{
>  \left( 1+{{\rm e}^{x}} \right) ^{2}}}{dx}=  \int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {{u}^{-iw}}{ \left( 1+u \right) ^{2}}}{du}. $$

Now, the last integral is nothing but the Mellin transform of the function $\frac{1}{(1+u)^2}$ with $s=1-iw$ which is given by

> $$ I = \frac{\pi w}{\sinh(\pi w)} $$

**Note:** To find the Mellin transform of the function $\frac{1}{(1+u)^2}$, you can use the $\beta$ function. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124) for the technique.

Comment: that is Mellin? or Laplace?

Comment: @oldrinb: You are right. It is corrected. It happens a lot. One has something in his mind and writes something else. Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Mhenni Benghorbal: How did you arrive at $\sinh(\pi w)$? That strongly resembles Euler's Gamma reflection formula, but it's $\sin(\pi w)$ in the denominator. Also should I make the substitution $x=1/u-1$? Thanks.

Comment: @user3100957: put $x=\frac{1}{1+u}$. Yes, you will need the reflection formula.