# How to compute this integral involving sech?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Does anybody know how to so solve this integral:

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\text{sech}(t-h)\,e^{ikt/\epsilon}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
and where $h\in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Is complex analysis a tool that may be used?

Comment: @AlexNelson I'm not very good in complex analysis. I guess that must be the way. I tried with some software without results. Is there any software that can solve this by using complex variable analysis?

$\epsilon$ is small and positive.

Comment: Is $h\in\mathbb{R}$? If not, that would complicate matters.

Comment: If $h$ is real, this is a Fourier transform. @Ambesh is this for homework?

Comment: @AlexSchiff $h$ is real. This is not really homework. My aim was to find the Melnikov function of some orbits. And by doing some computations I reached to this integral where I got stuck. 
I know about Fourier series, but not Fourier transform. One of my steps was to do the fourier series of a function. That is why the exponential term is there.

Comment: I think you might want to consider the [stationary phase approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation)...or method of steepest descent, whichever (I always get them confused!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get simpler (at least typographically) expressions, first we substitute $u = t+h$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikt/\epsilon}}{\cosh (t-h)}\,dt = e^{ikh/\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iku/\epsilon}}{\cosh u}\,du.$$

Also, let's write $c = k/\epsilon$ to simplify notation further.

The integrand is an entire meromorphic function, with simple poles in $i\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi,\; n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We evaluate the integral by considering a rectangular contour $C_R$ with vertices at $-R,R,R+\pi i, -R+\pi i$, and letting $R\to \infty$. By the residue theorem,

$$\int_{C_R} \frac{e^{icz}}{\cosh z}\,dz = 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{e^{icz}}{\cosh z}; \frac{\pi i}{2}\right) = 2\pi i\frac{e^{-c\pi/2}}{\sinh \frac{\pi i}{2}} = 2\pi e^{-c\pi/2}.$$

The integrals over the vertical sides of the rectangle tend to $0$ as $R\to \infty$, since $\lvert e^{icz}\rvert = e^{-c\operatorname{Im} z} \leqslant e^{\lvert c\rvert\pi}$ is bounded independently of $R$, and $\cosh (\pm R + it)\to \infty$ uniformly for $t\in[0,\pi]$ as $R\to\infty$.

For the integral over the side on the line $\operatorname{Im} z = \pi$, since $\cosh (z+\pi i) = - \cosh z$, we obtain

$$\int_{-R+\pi i}^{R+\pi i} \frac{e^{icz}}{\cosh z}\,dz = \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{icz}e^{-c\pi}}{-\cosh z}\,dz = -e^{-c\pi}\int_{-R}^R\frac{e^{icz}}{\cosh z}\,dz,$$

so

$$2\pi e^{-c\pi/2} = \left(1+e^{-c\pi}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{icu}}{\cosh u}\,du,$$

and

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{icu}}{\cosh u}\,du = \frac{2\pi e^{-c\pi/2}}{1+e^{-c\pi}} = \frac{2\pi}{e^{c\pi/2}+e^{-c\pi/2}} = \frac{\pi}{\cosh \frac{c\pi}{2}}.$$

Expanding $c$ and gathering the factor from the substitution at the beginning,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikt/\epsilon}}{\cosh (t-h)}\,dt = e^{\large \frac{ikh}{\epsilon}}\frac{\pi}{\cosh \frac{k\pi}{2\epsilon}}.$$

Comment: Are you missing the residue at $-\frac{\pi i}{2}$? Or am I mistaken? EDIT: Nevermind, read the contour incorrectly.

Comment: @AlexSchiff What do you mean? The residue is not right?

Comment: Just ignore my comment, sorry.

Comment: @Ambesh He first thought the contour enclosed two poles, $\pi i/2$ and $-\pi i/2$, and therefore, that I forgot one residue. But he misread the contour, hence his "Nevermind" edit.

Comment: Thank you @DanielFischer, and to all of you. I will review all the steps to understand this method.

Comment: I figured out Wolfram Alpha's syntax for Fourier transforms, and it  [agrees with](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Exp%5B%28i*k*h%29%2Fepsilon%5D*Sqrt%5B2Pi%5D*FourierTransform%5BSech%5Bx%5D%2Cx%2Ck%2Fepsilon%5D) @DanielFischer's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607141/fourier-transform-of-fx-frac1exe-x2/607396#607396). Here is another approach using the Mellin transform technique. First we write the integral as

> $$ I = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\text{sech}(t-h)\,e^{ikt/\epsilon}\,\mathrm{d}t= e^{\frac{ik}{\epsilon}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\text{sech}(t)\,e^{ikt/\epsilon}\,\mathrm{d}t= 2\,e^{\frac{ik}{\epsilon}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{ikt/\epsilon}}{e^{t}+e^{-t}}\,\mathrm{d}t.  $$

To finish the problem follow the [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607141/fourier-transform-of-fx-frac1exe-x2).