# Integral $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^4}{(\alpha+x^2)^4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Hi I am trying to show $$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^4}{(\alpha+x^2)^4}dx=\frac{\pi}{32\alpha^{3/2}},\quad \Re(\sqrt \alpha)> 0.
$$
I am looking for a solution to this NOT using contour integration, but real analysis methods.  Thanks.

For the complex case, we have poles at $\pm i\sqrt\alpha$, 4th order.

Comment: @AlexR 4th order Pole at $i\sqrt \alpha$, but I do not want to use residues.  I want a real analytic method.  Thanks

Comment: Check this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124).

Comment: @Integrals I know this is only form of Beta function, but unfortunately I'm late Jeff. I handle another integral problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{4} \over \pars{\alpha + x^{2}}^4}\,\dd x
     ={\pi \over 32\alpha^{3/2}}\,,\quad \Re\pars{\root{\alpha}} > 0:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}
> \color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{4} \over \pars{\alpha + x^{2}}^4}\,\dd x}
> &=\half\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{3/2} \over \pars{\alpha + x}^4}\,\dd x
> ={1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{1/2} \over \pars{\alpha + x}^{3}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-1/2} \over \pars{\alpha + x}^{2}}
> \,\dd x
> \end{align}

With $\ds{t \equiv x^{1/2}\quad\imp\quad x = t^{2}\,,\quad \dd x = 2t\,\dd t}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{4} \over \pars{\alpha + x^{2}}^4}\,\dd x}
&={1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \pars{\alpha + t^{2}}^{2}}
={1 \over 8\alpha^{3/2}}\lim_{\mu \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\mu/\root{\alpha}}
{\dd t \over \pars{1 + t^{2}}^{2}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 8\alpha^{3/2}}\lim_{\mu \to \infty}
\int_{0}^{\mu\pars{\root{\alpha}}^{*}}
{\dd t \over \pars{1 + t^{2}}^{2}}
={1 \over 8\alpha^{3/2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \pars{1 + t^{2}}^{2}}
\end{align}

> We'll replace $\ds{t = \root{\alpha}\tan\pars{\theta}}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{4} \over \pars{\alpha + x^{2}}^4}\,\dd x}
> &={1 \over 8\alpha^{3/2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
> ={1 \over 8\alpha^{3/2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{1 + \cos\pars{2\theta} \over 2}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 8\alpha^{3/2}}\,\pars{\half\,{\pi \over 2}}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{4} \over \pars{\alpha + x^{2}}^4}\,\dd x
={\pi \over 32\alpha^{3/2}}}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I think you just forgot the factor of $\pi$ in the final result.  +1 !

Comment: @Integrals Fine. I just fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the substitution $x=\sqrt{\alpha}\tan\theta$, to get:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan^4\theta \sec^2\theta}{\alpha^{3/2} \sec^8\theta}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{\alpha^{3/2}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^4\theta \cos^2\theta\,d\theta$$

It can be easily shown that:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^4\theta \cos^2\theta\,d\theta=\frac{\pi}{32}$$
Hence,
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^4}{(\alpha+x^2)^4}dx=\frac{\pi}{32\alpha^{3/2}}$$

Comment: This is what I was looking for also.  What a nice real method.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: If you like integrals, take a look around I post a few you may like.  Thanks for this solution.

Comment: I have already seen them and to be honest, they are too difficult for me at the moment. They seem to involve stuff (like complex analysis) which I haven't yet come across but I constantly follow your posts. :)

Comment: Well thank you, likewise I enjoy your solutions on all 6 posts you made.  +6

Comment: @Integrals Jeff, let me introduce you to [Pranav](https://brilliant.org/profile/pranav-zt2nnf/feed/). He is a friend of mine since I were an avid user on [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/). He is really good on calculus and physics problems. You can check his profile there. :)

Comment: I am not even remotely close to you guys in Calculus, I am still learning. :3

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thank you my friend and thank you Pranav for solving some problems of mine!  It is nice to meet you my friend!

Comment: We are all still learning Pranav. Anyway, I also vote up almost all of your answers recently. Really nice answers. :) $$\\$$ I also always follow your posts Jeff. :) 
@Integrals

Comment: @Tunk-Fey English is not my native tongue either. :)  Thank you for making this point clear in the discussion about writing proper English and LaTex.

Answer (score 2):

Small Hint) substituting $x=\alpha^{1/2}u$, you can pull the dependency on the parameter $\alpha$ outside the integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^4}{(\alpha+x^2)^4}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\alpha^2u^4}{\alpha^4(1+u^2)^4}\alpha^{1/2}du=\frac{1}{a^{3/2}}\int_0^\infty \frac{u^4}{(1+u^2)^4}du.$$

Comment: That is not really a hint at all.  This is pretty standard, how would you handle the integral you have in terms of u?

Comment: @Integrals Substitute $t=u^2$, and use $$B(x,y)=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}dx,$$

where $B(x,y)= \frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ is the beta function.

Comment: @Integrals Partial fractions would be my next step. I'd be curious to see if expanding in partial fractions before or after Alyosha's substitution is easier.

Comment: @DavidH Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> *I am looking for a solution to this NOT using contour integration, but real analysis methods.*

All integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{(1+x^m)^p}$ are solved by letting $t=\dfrac1{(1+x^m)^p}$ , then recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, and using Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties). In this case, we first have to factor $\alpha$ outside of the parenthesis, and let $y^m=\dfrac{x^m}\alpha$. But you already knew this, since you said that you are familiar with many of my other answers on the same topic.

Comment: Before reading the name, I knew who did this post because of what you wrote:)!  I guess this will suffice, but really I was looking for some clever substitutions not involving special functions.  But I do not mind special functions, Thanks +1

Comment: See Felix solution above for what I was looking for.

Comment: @Integrals: See [Mick Jagger's reply](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM_p1Az05Jo&t=63) to mathematical expectations. :-)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Keith Richards & Mick both wrote that song together. I do not think it was just Jagger who wrote that.  :)