# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{y^{n}}{(1+y^2)^2}dy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I wishing to calculating the integral$$
I:=\int_0^\infty \frac{y^{n}}{(1+y^2)^2}dy \qquad n=0,1,2
$$
 I am looking for real analytic solutions thanks, the closed form is cosecant function so it is very nice.

My input can be from a complex analytic method only:
Note, we have double poles at $y=\pm i$.    We close contour around a complex function $f(z)=z^n(1+z^2)^{-2}$ in the upper half plane to obtain
$$
\text{Res}_{z=i}=\frac{1}{4i}, \ (n=2)\quad \text{Res}_{z=i}=0, \ (n=1)\quad \text{Res}_{z=i}=\frac{1}{2i}, \ (n=0).
$$
Now we can write $2\pi i \cdot \text{Res}_{z=i} \ \forall \ n=0,1,2 $.  And then we can finish the problem.  But I wish to calculate I by real analysis methods, thanks.

Comment: Are you going through some book and just posting all the integrals to this website?

Comment: I haven't got time to look at the details right now, but couldn't you use the product rule a few times to express this in terms of integrands that have explicit evaluation?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, that is quite rude though.  If you can find all of the integrals I post in a book, please post it.

Comment: With $\displaystyle{\large y = \sqrt{1 - t \over t}}$ you will arrive to a Beta function.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thank you friend

Comment: Sorry, just trying to figure out what you're up to. It's kind of weird to post nothing but integrals, and dozens of them.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am retired and studied mathematics when growing up quite competitively so now one of my hobbies is integration.  I post many integrals because this is a math website and I hope that it is of interest to everybody on here.  They are not for homework and MOST are not in books.  It's just a hobby and I apologize if it makes you annoyed.  It is all in the love of integration and sharing math problems...

Comment: Have a look in  Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, most certain it is there. I know I have seen similar integrals

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Thank you my friend it sure is. I have had Gradshteyn and Ryzhik for a very long time.  This question is also in many other books though.  However, I like to see new solutions.  For ex: look at the solution to this problem in which I checked

Comment: It's weird that a user named @Integrals posts integrals? It's no mystery - the (wo)man likes integrals.

Comment: @BennettGardiner Thank you my friend! and I prefer my gender to be described by being a definite or indefinite integral.  Not male/female.

Comment: That's ok, I find it strange that people question motives when it comes to the problems they like on this site. I also notice @GerryMyerson has only asked 2 questions ever - and fully half of those are definite integrals!

Comment: @BennettGardiner Yes I am also quite confused as to why sometimes people question my problems in such a manner.  This is a math website after all so it is about sharing problems with one another.       Thank you my friend- Integrand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$I_m(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^n}{a+y^m}dy$$. Then $-I_2'(1) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^n}{(1+y^2)^2}$ is your integral.
Write $$I_m(a) = \frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^n}{1+(y/a^{1/m})^m}dy \\= \frac{1}{a} a^\frac{n+1}{m}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^n}{1+u^m}du\\ = a^{\frac{n+1}{m}-1} \frac{\pi}{m \sin{\frac{\pi (n+1)}{m}}}.$$
Here I used an obvious substitution and an integral that can be found using the Beta function.
This gives $$-I_2'(1) = \frac{1-n}{2} \frac{\pi}{2} \csc{\frac{\pi}{2}(n+1)} = \frac{1-n}{4} \pi \sec{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Did you check your result numerically?  Very nice solution and nice technique

Comment: I checked it for m = 2, n = $\sqrt(3)$ and it gave the (exact) right answer.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. i have verified too now.  Very nice...Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Make the change of variables $1+y^2 = \frac{1}{u}$ and then use the [$\beta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124).

Comment: See also [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties).