# What's the integral of $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^4+1)^5}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^4+1)^5}$$

My answer would be : $\dfrac{\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{4})\Gamma(\tfrac{19}{4})}{4\Gamma(5)}$

Solution: You can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124) technique. –  Mhenni Benghorbal

Comment: If this is $your$ answer, what have you done ?

Comment: If you are only interested in the answer, you can check WolframAlpha to confirm that it is correct: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%281%2Bx%5E4%29%5E5+from+x+%3D+0+to+infinity http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%5B1%2F4%5DGamma%5B19%2F4%5D%2F%284Gamma%5B5%5D%29

Comment: @JimmyK4542. I wonder how to compute the antiderivative. Any idea ?

Comment: Here's what I've done: [link](http://i57.tinypic.com/25fm4qt.jpg). I checked wolfram and it seems right, not sure though.

Comment: $u = \dfrac{x}{x+1} = 1-\dfrac{1}{x+1},\quad{}$ $x = \dfrac{1}{1-u} - 1 = \dfrac{u}{1-u},\quad{}$ $dx = \dfrac{du}{(1-u)^2},\quad{}$ $x^4+1 = \left( \dfrac{u}{1-u} \right)^4 + 1.\quad{}$ $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\cdots\,dx = \int_0^1\cdots\,du.\quad{}$ Dunno if this will work.  Maybe I'll try something more pedestrian. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You can use this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thanks, that's how I approached this. Mind checking out this [solve](http://i57.tinypic.com/25fm4qt.jpg) and telling me if it is correct ?

Comment: @RustinAlexandru: Good job. It is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and help !

Answer (score 6):

Using the very good method suggested and recommended by   Mhenni Benghorbal, the problem becomes effectively quite simple. Using $$1+x^4=\frac{1}{t}$$ we then have $$x=\frac{\sqrt[4]{1-t}}{\sqrt[4]{t}}$$ $$dx=-\frac{1}{4 (1-t)^{3/4} t^{5/4}}$$ $$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^4+1)^5}=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 t^{15/4} (1-t)^{-3/4} ~dt =\frac{1}{4} B\left(\frac{19}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right) $$ The final result can be written in many different forms and in particular in terms of $\Gamma$ as you posted; in fcat, the result simplifies to $\frac{1155 \pi }{4096 \sqrt{2}}$.

More generally, still using the same technique, you could easily establish $$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^m+1)^n}=\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right) \Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{m}\right)}{\Gamma
   (n)}$$ provided $\Re(m n)>1\land \Re(m)>0$.

Going even further,$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^p~~dx}{(x^m+1)^n}=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{p+1}{m}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{m n-p-1}{m}\right)}{m
   \Gamma (n)}$$ provided $\Re(m n-p)>1\land \Re(p)>-1\land \Re(m)>0$.

I should underline that, for your specific problem, trying to compute first the antiderivative would have been a small nightmare (a CAS allowed to generate a quite long expression).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very helpful. Appreciated.

Comment: You are very welcome but all credit should be given to  Mhenni Benghorbal. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = \sqrt{\tan \theta}$. Then, $dx = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\tan \theta}}\cdot \sec^2 \theta d\theta =\dfrac{d\theta}{2\sin^{1/2}\theta\cos^{3/2} \theta}$. If $x = 0$, $\theta = 0$ and if $x \to \infty \ \Rightarrow \ \theta = \pi/2$.

$I =\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{(x^4 + 1)^5} = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\cos^{10}\theta d\theta}{\sin^{1/2}\theta\cos^{3/2}\theta} = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{-1/2}\theta\cos^{17/2}\theta d\theta$

[Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function): $B(x,y) = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2x - 1}\theta \cos^{2y - 1}\theta d\theta $

Thus, $x = 1/4$ and $y = 19/4$ and $I = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2}B(1/4,19/4) = \dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(19/4)}{\Gamma(5)}$

Answer (score 2):

The result is indeed true, and the method used to derive it has already been described. Now all that's left is to simplify it by using Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties), in order to finally arrive

at the desired result, $~I=\dfrac{1155}{2^{12}}\cdot\dfrac\pi{\sqrt2}$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
x^4+1 & = (x^4 +2x^2 + 1)-2x^2 \\[8pt]
& = (x^2+1)^2 - (\sqrt{2}\, x)^2 \\[8pt]
& = (x^2 - \sqrt{2}\, x +1)(x^2 + \sqrt{2}\, x + 1)
\end{align}

Then go to partial fractions.

Comment: Just by curiosity, did you try continuing the calculations.