# Improper integral with removable discontinuity

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate , for $ \alpha > 2 $

$ \int_0^{\infty}\!\frac{x-1}{x^\alpha-1}\, dx. $

I would be intertest for any replies or any comments

Comment: See a [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $\alpha>2$ we have:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x-1}{x^\alpha-1}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{\alpha\sin\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}}\tag{1}$$
since the LHS is related with the Euler Beta function and the $\Gamma$ function satisfies:
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}.$$

Comment: Can you please post a proof of the formula? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several methods (direct integration involving hypergeometric2F1 function for example). The method shown in attachment uses known properties of the digamma function.

[image]