# Expressing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx/(x^2+1)^n$ in terms of Gamma function

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, gamma-function, closed-form

How to prove this identity for $n>1/2$? 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^n}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot \Gamma(n-\frac{1}{2}) }{\Gamma (n)}$$

Comment: [Related techniques](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Due to parity, $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)~dx=2\cdot\int_0^\infty f(x)~dx.~$ Then, let $t=\dfrac1{1+x^2}$ , and recognize the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral.