# Improper integral of rational function $k^2/(1+a^2k^2)^2$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I've got the integral $\int^\infty_{-\infty} dk \frac{k^2}{(1+a^2 k^2)^2}$ where $a$ is a real number.  I can't seem to find a $u$-substitution or trigonometric substitution that will work.  Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $a>0$,

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{x^2\,dx}{(1+a^2 x^2)^2}&=&\frac{1}{a^3}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{x^2\,dx}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{a^3}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{a^3}\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2a^3}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
The two integrals $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2}$ can be evaluated by simply computing the residue of the integrand function in the pole with positive imaginary part $x=i$.

Hence we have, for any $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$:

> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{x^2\,dx}{(1+a^2 x^2)^2}=\frac{\pi}{2|a|^3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Try $u = \tan(k)/a$.  Be careful when handling the endpoints.

Comment: With tangent, how can you evaluate what the limits of integration will be?  $\tan(\infty)$ is undefined.

Comment: But the image of (-pi/2, pi/2) under tan will cover the entire real line like you want.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write the integral as

> $$ I = 2\int^\infty_{0} dk \frac{k^2}{(1+a^2 k^2)^2}. $$

Use the change of variables $1+a^2k^2=\frac{1}{u}$ which will cast the integral in terms of the beta function

> $$ I = \frac{1}{a^3} \int^1_{0} u^{-1/2}(1-u)^{1/2}du =\frac{1}{a^3} \frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(2)}=\frac{\Gamma(1/2)^2}{2a^3} = \frac{\pi}{4a^3}. $$

See [related techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254417/how-to-solve-this-question-related-to-definite-integration).

**Note:** The beta function is defined as

> $$ \mathrm{\beta}(x,y) = \int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,\mathrm{d}t \,\quad Re(x)>0,\, Re(y)>0.  $$

**Notes:**

1)

> $$ \Gamma(1/2)= \sqrt{\pi}. $$

2) **It is a general technique that allows you to handle more harder problems as you can see in the links.**

Comment: I think this is a bit "nuking the mosquito".

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: No comments.

Comment: I was meaning no offense, @Mhenni Benghorbal. You are clearly right, but there is a shortcut to get the answer without invoking the Euler Beta function. I just think "the easier, the better".

Comment: I think you've got an extra factor of 1/2.

Comment: @user174420: You are right. I forgot to multiply by $2$ whiches is in the first integral.

Comment: @mhenni, no you didn't forget, you just multiplied your final answer by 1/2 accidentally.